# How do I disable proguard for building my Android app?

Tags: android

It used to be that proguard was controlled by project.properties, but that's no longer the case, and the Android documentation has not been updated. The project.properties file now clearly states that the it is generated by Android Tools and changes will be erased. I've tried commenting out the proguard.config line, but when I compile, it rewrites the project.properties, and continues to use proguard. What is the current method of disabling proguard? Thanks!

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt:proguard-google-api-client.txt

# Project target.
target=android-17
android.library.reference.1=../../../../android-sdk-linux/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
```

Comment: Did you try to delete the directory with the mappings which are created by proguard?

Comment: Do you have the latest SDK? When I generate a new project and look at my `project.properties` the ProGuard line is commented out by default and the comment above it says to *un*comment it to enable ProGuard...

Comment: @rekire good call, thank you! I deleted the proguard dir under my project, and commented out the proguard.config line again and have successfully disabled proguard. Thank you!

Comment: @piusvelte if his answered helped you - mark it as accepted

Comment: @kape123 I didn't see an option to accept a comment as the answer. I see that he's now added and answer, which I've accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to delete the proguard directory in your project. So proguard will forget its mapping.

Comment: could you please give me the steps to delete it .. i am beginner with xamarin

Comment: I never used xamarin, I would expect that you don't use proguard and if then not by default.

Comment: could you please give me the steps to delete it

Comment: @ShirishHerwade I expect that you use gradle: In that case run `./gradlew clean`

Answer (score 37):

set this

```
minifyEnabled false
```

in your app `build.gradle`

Like this:

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false 
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
```

Comment: minifyEnabled is set to false by default

Answer (score 27):

set

```
 useProguard false
```

in your app build.gradle

like

```
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        useProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: Best answer! Should be the definitive!

Comment: as of 2020/06 -> The setting "useProguard" is being deprecated, and will be removed in Android Studio 3.5, see issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129758703

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried to add the next line to your proguard configuration file (to the beginning of the file) :

```
-dontobfuscate
```

?

Comment: This disables obfuscation but not minification

Comment: @Sam I think the minification is in another flag. This answer is very old. I don't know what changed ever since..

Answer (score 0):

According to the [React-Native Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html), To disable Proguard, set def **enableProguardInReleaseBuilds** to false in your android/app/build.gradle:

```
/**
* Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
*/
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false // Instead of true
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case
1 ->
add this line in the android tag:

```
 android {
    def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false // Instead of true
```

2 ->  then add this line

```
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources = false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

I hope it will work for you