# How to turn off proguard completely?

Tags: android, proguard, java

I have an Android application on which I don't want to do anything regarding optimization/obfuscation/etc.

I deleted the (auto-generated) proguard configuration file (proguard.cfg) but I think my library projects' files are still being obfuscated, because in the crash reports I don't see the line numbers - `Unknown Source` is shown instead.

How can I turn off proguard completely?

Also, how can I validate that it was indeed turned off?

Comment: Are you using Android Studio (Gradle) or Eclipse?

Comment: Have you tried removing the **proguard-project.txt** file, edit **project.properties** and comment out the lines referring to **proguard.config**, and remove the proguard directory from your Android project?

Comment: I use eclipse. Does it matter? The apk is built using ant.

Answer (score 6):

set this

```
minifyEnabled false
```

in your app `build.gradle`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39051307/2002079

Comment: Doesn't work on latest flutter

Answer (score 2):

1. In your project folder create or edit proguard.cfg
2. Add this to proguard.cfg

   `-dontoptimize
   -dontshrink
   -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
   -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
   -dontpreverify
   -verbose`
3. Add to project.properties this:

`proguard.config=proguard.cfg`

4. form console run:

   `ant clean
   ant release`

Comment: dude, ant is not even default on AS

Answer (score 1):

```
    debug/release(as per your need) {
        minifyEnabled false
        useProguard false

    }
```

Comment: This is WRONG. `useProguard false` does not disable obfuscation; it changes the obfuscation engine from ProGuard to R8. See the docs for `useProguard` for more info.

Answer (score -2):

**UPDATE** : DISABLING THE USE PROGUARD NOW ENABLES R8 CODE SHRINKER BY DEFAULT .

1. **minifyEnabled** is **code shrinker**

   2. **shrinkResources** is **resource shrinker** (works only when minifyEnabled true)
   3. **useProguard** is **code obfuscator**
   4. You can use **minifyEnabled true** with **useProguard false**

   So, for completely disabling the proguard features do :

> minifyEnabled false useProguard false