# Can't generate signed APK in Android Studio, because proguard-rules.txt is missing

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, proguard

I have a problem with generating signed APK in Android Studio. After fixing all the warnings I am stuck on this one:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/franek/Documents/Android_Studio_Melange/app/proguard-rules.txt (No such file or directory)

I don't want to change minifyEnabled to false, because I want to keep Proguard working. How can I fix this error?

A fragment of build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
}
```

should work ok, as long as you don't need any special ProGuard configuration. If you do, use your original `proguardFiles` entry and create the file

> /Users/franek/Documents/Android_Studio_Melange/app/proguard-rules.txt

Then put your custom rules in this file.

Answer (score 6):

Delete folder **build** inside **app** folder, then regenerate.

Comment: This helps me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try delete folder build inside app folder.[image]

Then regenerate.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to disable the proguard

you can follow these steps: (to disable the proguard)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72272882/10340870

it works for me. After disable the pro guards I'm able to generate the signed aab file

Answer (score -2):

I realise this question has been long answered, but I had the same problem and have been trying for hours to fix it. None of the solutions on here worked for me, so I'm adding this to save others the trouble.

I solved the issue just by completely getting rid of the proguardFiles line, so my code looks like:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
    }
}
```

Of course this doesn't help if you need a specific proguard file, but I thought I had to specify one and it turned out I didn't. I hope this helps!

Comment: This seems like it might be dangerous, since the default ProGuard files protect a bunch of Android platform stuff from obfuscation: see e.g. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/7dd444ea0125e50a5e88604afb6de43e80b7c270/files/proguard-android.txt You can guess what might break by looking at the classes in this list.

Comment: My app runs fine after exporting through this proguard configuration, and does properly obfuscate the code, although you are probably correct. However since I couldn't get it to work any other way, this is the only option I could find.