# Unable to generate signed apk with proguard

Tags: android, google-play-services, proguard, android-multidex, signed-apk

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to generate a signed apk with proguard enabled.

```
Error:Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstMethodRef cannot be cast to com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstInterfaceMethodRef
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a></li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
<a href="stopGradleDaemons">Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</a></li><li>Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.</li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

This is what I'm using/doing:

1. Android studio 2.2
2. play-services version 9.6.1
3. proguard-rules.pro

   - `dontwarn okio.`
   - `dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8`
   - `keep public class com.google.android.gms.`
   - `dontwarn com.google.android.gms.`
   - `keepattributes InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod`
4. gradle(app)

   ```
   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.something.something"
       minSdkVersion 15
       targetSdkVersion 23
       versionCode 3
       versionName "3.0"

       // Enabling multidex support.
       multiDexEnabled true

       testInstrumentationRunner "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled true
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
   productFlavors {
   }
   ```
5. Libraries that I'm using:

   - `com.radiusnetworks:proximitykit-android:0.+@aar`
   - `com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2`
   - `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1`

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28258461/5832311), the code below should work as long as you don't need any special ProGuard configuration.

> ```
> buildTypes {
>     release {
>         minifyEnabled true
>         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> If you do, use your original `proguardFiles` entry and create the file `/Users/franek/Documents/Android_Studio_Melange/app/proguard-rules.txt` then put your custom rules in this file.

This [thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=198963) might also help. Add the following lines to the `proguard-rules.pro` file to resolve the issue of being unable to generate a signed APK using Proguard `(Minify Enabled = true)`.

> keep class org.apache.http.**
> keep class android.net.http.**
> dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

Comment: I once had to set minifyEnabled = false for mine to work!