# Sinch tutorial gradle build errors

Tags: android, gradle, sinch

Im trying to get sinch going, and I am following their tutorial form here.
https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-messaging-tutorial-using-sinch-and-parse/

step one is download the skelton and do the gradle build, however first error was unsporrted version of gradle. android studio fixed it automatically and re-imported. and then i get this error:

Error:(15, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'
Possible causes:

The project 'messenger' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

I'm new to android programming and android studio, so I'm kinda lost. How can i get this built and continue with the tutorial?

Comment: try to disable proguard and then try

Comment: I commented out the line and it built. this wont be a problem later?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031386/how-do-i-disable-proguard-for-building-my-android-app

Comment: If you used my answer below, could you please mark it as accepted? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To comply with the newer versions of Gradle, change 'runProguard' to 'minifyEnabled'

Answer (score 1):

in my case, i am using sinch 3.11.1.
it is aar file.
so you need to import aar file.
after that you can use sinch on your project.
to import aar file you can follow this video (it is not mine):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-GbMTa1fX0

hope it helps.