# Android Studio 3.3, Advanced Profiling is Unavailable for the Selected Process

Tags: android-profiler, android-studio-3.3

I updated my android studio to version 3.3 and stuck with the android profiler problem "Advanced profiling is unavailable for the selected process".

I have tried the followings but nothing worked

1. Run Configuration -> Enable advanced profiling
2. minifyEnabled false (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39051307/1925394)
3. different compileSdkVersion 25, 26, 28

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting Run Configuration to Enable advanced profiling and then re-running/building the app did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

After trying the solution mentioned here and on other similar questions, and none of them actually working for me.

I tried `Cleaning the project` and `Rebuilding it`. And Voila! It worked!!